# Facebook Omniauth routing error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I followed [Rails Casts Episode #360](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) on how to integrate facebook login.

When I click 'Sign in with Facebook', I get this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook"
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Frostfiress::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  get "profiles/show"
  #get 'questions/:tag', to: 'questions#index', as: :tag
  #get 'places/:tag', to: 'places#index', as: :tag
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :places


  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do 
      get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
      get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
      get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
      get 'password/change', to: 'devise/passwords#edit', as: :password
  end

  resources :answers

  resources :questions


  root :to => "questions#index"

  get '/:username', to: 'profiles#show'
```

All of the other files I had to change in the RailsCast are exactly the same as in the tutorial.

My AppId and Secret were working but now I get the routing error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

This is the result of rake routes:

```
profiles_show GET        /profiles/show(.:format)                  profiles#show
                                          /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)        sessions#create
                  auth_failure            /auth/failure(.:format)                   :controller#:action
                       signout            /signout(.:format)                        sessions#destroy
                        places GET        /places(.:format)                         places#index
                               POST       /places(.:format)                         places#create
                     new_place GET        /places/new(.:format)                     places#new
                    edit_place GET        /places/:id/edit(.:format)                places#edit
                         place GET        /places/:id(.:format)                     places#show
                               PUT        /places/:id(.:format)                     places#update
                               DELETE     /places/:id(.:format)                     places#destroy
              new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
                  user_session POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)                  devise/sessions#create
          destroy_user_session DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
       user_omniauth_authorize            /users/auth/:provider(.:format)           devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/(?!)/}
        user_omniauth_callback            /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)    devise/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:(?!))
                 user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#create
             new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
            edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
                               PUT        /users/password(.:format)                 devise/passwords#update
      cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)                   devise/registrations#cancel
             user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#create
         new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)                  devise/registrations#new
        edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                     devise/registrations#edit
                               PUT        /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#update
                               DELETE     /users(.:format)                          devise/registrations#destroy
                      register GET        /register(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
                         login GET        /login(.:format)                          devise/sessions#new
                        logout GET        /logout(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
                      password GET        /password/change(.:format)                devise/passwords#edit
                       answers GET        /answers(.:format)                        answers#index
                               POST       /answers(.:format)                        answers#create
                    new_answer GET        /answers/new(.:format)                    answers#new
                   edit_answer GET        /answers/:id/edit(.:format)               answers#edit
                        answer GET        /answers/:id(.:format)                    answers#show
                               PUT        /answers/:id(.:format)                    answers#update
                               DELETE     /answers/:id(.:format)                    answers#destroy
                     questions GET        /questions(.:format)                      questions#index
                               POST       /questions(.:format)                      questions#create
                  new_question GET        /questions/new(.:format)                  questions#new
                 edit_question GET        /questions/:id/edit(.:format)             questions#edit
                      question GET        /questions/:id(.:format)                  questions#show
                               PUT        /questions/:id(.:format)                  questions#update
                               DELETE     /questions/:id(.:format)                  questions#destroy
                          root            /                                         questions#index
                               GET        /:username(.:format)                      profiles#show
```

Comment: Does running rake routes show the omniauth routes?

Comment: @Nazar These are the only routes I can see to do with omniauth                         /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)        sessions#create
                  auth_failure            /auth/failure(.:format)                   :controller#:action
                       signout            /signout(.:format)                        sessions#destroy

Comment: What version of Devise are you using?

Comment: @varunvlalan just the normal Devise 2.0

Comment: run rake routes and post the output

Comment: try using '/user/auth/facebook'

Comment: I used the [OmniAuth Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) to get omniauth-facebook going, and found it a little different from the RailsCast. One example is the `devise_for` line, which is `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }` in the Overview. Have a look through that wiki to see if any of it is helpful to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

The route /auth/facebook isn't generated automatically, and if it were there it wouldn't actually do anything unless you mapped it to some controller function. However you shouldn't need to do this.

Make sure that you're actually sending a request to facebook, otherwise omniauth won't be able to do anything.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

You should handle facebook's response to your request by either redirecting to /auth/facebook/callback on a success or /auth/failure on a failure.

Comment: /auth/facebook is generated by the omniauth gem and the middleware that is added.